# Express Js Firebase SignOut() immeditately returning status 200 to client side Fetch Post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I'm making a POST request using Fetch on my client side javascript to my server side javascript that is using Express Js and Firebase Auth. The auth().signOut() is returning a 200 code, but the .then part of my code is never executed as the function immeditely returns the response to the client side fetch; therefore never rendering my next view. How do I make my server side code return a 200 status to my client side code only after the .then part of my server side code is executed?

Here is my code:

Server Side:

```
var logoutController = {

    //post logout user function
    logout: function(req, res, next) {
        var context, view;

        firebase.auth().signOut().then(function(data){
            view = 'index';
            context = {
                error: false,
            };
            res.render(view, context);

        }).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            view = 'index'; //Change to an error page
            context = {
                error: true,
            };
            res.render(view, context);
        });

    }, 

} //end logoutController

router.post("/logout", logoutController.logout);
```

Client Side code:

```
var button = document.getElementById("logoutButton");

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    fetch('/logout', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        return;
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert(error);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to use in the client side:

window.location.pathname = '/'

To make a redirection to the page I wanted the user to go to after he logged out.